# Tengo un ListView en un fragmet y quiero ir a otro fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

cuando ejecuto la app se cierra. Este es el error:

> 01-18 12:33:01.371 5953-5953/com.aguila0017.fruits E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.aguila0017.fruits, PID: 5953
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: com.aguila0017.fruits.MainActivity@2c0774
>   must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
>                                                                            at com.aguila0017.fruits.Uno_Cerezas.onAttach(Uno_Cerezas.java:47)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1048)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:838)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:878)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:719)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Este el el código del `Fragment` que contiene el `ListView`

```
    import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.Switch;



    public class DiezFrut extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public DiezFrut() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment DiezFrut.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static DiezFrut newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        DiezFrut fragment = new DiezFrut();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diez_frut, container, false);
        ListView dfrutas;
        String [] frutas;

        dfrutas = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.DiezFrutas);
        frutas=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Diezfrutas);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,frutas);
        dfrutas.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        dfrutas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                switch(i)
                {
                    case 0:getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,new Uno_Cerezas()).commit();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return view;



    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }




    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

y este el código del `Fragment` a donde quiero llegar:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Uno_Cerezas extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Uno_Cerezas() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uno__cerezas, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como quieres ir al otro fragment? con un click en un item del listview o algo así?

Comment: si, exacto. Con un setOnItemClickListener

Comment: en el primer codigo esta.

Answer (score 0):

En la actividad principal MainActivity debes implementar el InteractionListener también el de Uno_Cerezas.

```
implements DiezFrut.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Uno_Cerezas.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Al obtener la referencia del ListView, le asignas un listener `OnItemClickListener` esto para detectar la vista seleccionada en el listado.

Agrega `.addToBackStack(null)` al reemplazar el `Fragment`:

```
        dfrutas = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.DiezFrutas);

        dfrutas.setOnItemClickListener(
                        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            if (position == 0){
                            // Abre otro Fragment.
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,new Uno_Cerezas()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                            }


                        }
                    }
            );
```